# The number of left parentheses is greater than or equal to the number of right parentheses.

Tags: induction, propositional-calculus

Using induction on the complexity of formulas, let's assume that in every proper non-empty initial segment of a propositional formula, the number of left parentheses is greater than or equal to the number of right parentheses.

Note: A proper initial segment of a propositional formula  is an expression that starts and continues with the same symbols as  but does not include all symbols of .

Any thoughts?

Comment: Thoughts? Review the specification of "formula". Maybe you have the atomic case (no parentheses) and the negation case $(\lnot \varphi)$ and the binary connectives case. Start with atomic and negation cases.